# SAPUI5: Unable to navigate to particular wizard step when navigating from another view in SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5, wizard

I am using a Wizard in one view and after performing certain steps, I am navigating to the next view. Now, I have a requirement that when I navigate from the next view to this view which contains the wizard, then I should take the control back to the last step of the view with all the data persisted.

On the back navigation on the next view, I used the navTo function of router to navigate back to the first view containing the wizard. Also, in the first view, I haven't written discardSteps for the Wizard in the handleRouteMatched. But still the steps are getting discarded and we are getting the initial state of the wizard.

This is happening when we are executing the application for the first time. However; if we continue using the app, the app works fine the second time and we navigate to the last performed step in the wizard while navigating from the second view. Any idea what could be the issue and how it can be solved?

The setCurrentStep on handleRouteMatch for the first view containing the wizard doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I switch back from the review page (after wizard) back to a specific step in the wizard:

```
    _editStep: function (sStepId) {
        var fnAfterNavigate = function () {
            // Reset wizard to given step
            var oWizard = this.byId("wizard");
            var oStepToEdit = this.byId(sStepId);
            oWizard.goToStep(oStepToEdit);

            var oNavContainer = this.byId("nav-container");
            oNavContainer.detachAfterNavigate(fnAfterNavigate);
        }.bind(this);

        // Nav back to the create page, use callback to set wizard
        var oNavContainer = this.byId("nn-nav-container");
        oNavContainer.attachAfterNavigate(fnAfterNavigate);
        oNavContainer.backToTop();
    }
```

First I switch back to the wizard view, then the callback kicks in and sets the wizard to the correct step.

Comment: Hi, I am able to follow. What will be passed in sStepId? This is what I am doing:   onNavBack: function () {
   //this.oRouter.navTo("wizard");} and in handleRoute Matched of the wizard view; I am doing this:   var selfCheckInWizard = this.getView().byId("Wizard");
   
   Wizard.nextStep();
   Wizard.goToStep(that.getView().byId("Questionaire")); Any idea how your code fits in here

Comment: sStepId is the Id of the wizardstep you want to edit, in your case "Questionaire". You are usig router for navigation I used the navcontainer. Can you reproduce the error using this boilerplate https://jsfiddle.net/inui_io/pqn1cv63/ ?

Comment: Hi, I created two different routes for the same view while navigation from other views; This helped achieve the required functionality,

Answer (score 0):

I created two different routes for the same view while navigation from other views; This helped achieve the required functionality,